# HTML CSS Slideshow Transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I wrote a simple JavaScript code for a simple HTML slideshow; the images are in an array and changes every 5 seconds.

I am wanting at the 4th second of the current image for it to transition to `0 opacity` over `1 second`, meaning that once the image has transitioned and no longer visible, the next one should load, so as to create a smoother transition between all images.

My code is as follows.

CSS

```
#slider {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: -5px 7px 5px #888888;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 470px;
    align: middle;
}

#slider.fadeOut {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="slider" src="Images/image1">
```

JavaScript

```
var imgArray = [
    'Images/image1.jpg',
    'Images/image2.jpg',
    'Images/image3.jpg',
    'Images/image4.jpg',
    'Images/image5.jpg',
    'Images/image6.jpg',
    'Images/image7.jpg',
    'Images/image8.jpg'
  ],
curIndex = 0;

imgDuration = 5000;

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
        document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
    },1000);

    curIndex++;

    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
        curIndex = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```

The problem is the transitions are jumpy so an image will fade out over the 1 second and then the same image is still showing, then the next image will load without the transition.

I'm sure this is a simple fix I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because when you change `src` on the image, it still has to load the image file and you're not waiting for that to happen before you continue with the rest of your process.

Your method should load the image and use a callback function when it is completed, then do the remainder of your process.

**UPDATE:**

So I know your example uses CSS transitions and this uses jQuery but I wanted you to see the benefit of chaining callback functions.  If you look carefully at this, you can see how the img request isn't made until the fadeout is complete, then the script loads the img, and only when that load is complete, does it put the new image in the container and fade it in.  Then once that's faded in, the next callback calls the setTimeout again to keep it going.  This way all your actions happen sequentially.

```js
var imgArray = [
    'http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300',
    'http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200',
    'http://www.fillmurray.com/500/200',
    'http://www.fillmurray.com/300/600',
    'http://www.fillmurray.com/350/200',
    'http://www.fillmurray.com/300/350',
  ],
curIndex = 0;
imgDuration = 5000;

function slideShow() {
  $("#slider").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      var img = $("<img />").attr('src', imgArray[curIndex])
        .on('load', function() {
            $("#slider").html(img).fadeIn('normal',function(){
                curIndex++;
                if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
                    curIndex = 0;
                }
                setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
           });
            
        });
    }); 
}

slideShow();
```

```css
#slider {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: -5px 7px 5px #888888;
}

#slider img {
   width: 99vw;
   height: 470px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Are the images not loaded when they are added to the array though, I appreciate they haven't physically loaded on to the page but they are still present?

Comment: No they aren't. You would actually have to load the image content.  What you have in your array is simply strings.

Comment: Never really done callbacks had a quick read and wondered if this would be easier to do using a function for fading the picture and another function for sliding it along one step and just having a setTimeout method on both?

Comment: See the update I just posted and the snippet example for an explanation.